# datepicker-style calculator for text field input

Tags: jquery

Has anyone got a code for a little icon that I can place in/near text fields if the user wishes to add up some numbers and then have the results populate the text field?

Datepicker is exactly what I am looking for, but a standard calculator should pop up instead of a calendar.

Thanks!

```
    // datepicker
$("#Datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/datepicker.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    altField: "#actualDate",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"

});
```

CSS:

Comment: Did you even search ? https://www.google.com/search?q=calculater+image&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D10&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=Ng81UK-IA5TOyAG334GoBg&biw=1920&bih=955&sei=OA81UIzQF-WHywHFuIGwAg#q=calculator+icon&um=1&hl=en&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:24,iszh:24&tbm=isch&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=QA81UN3FMsPpygHj7oHwDw&ved=0CCsQpwUoBQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=572b344aecad0917&biw=1920&bih=955

Comment: Yes, I searched and searched but nothing came up that was even close.

Comment: Are you looking for a calculator script or an icon?

Comment: I got the icon, need the script like Datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following link. 
http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html

It works exactly like datepicker